# ffmpeg creates empty mpd-file

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, dash.js

I'm trying to live stream a webm file using ffmpeg and Dash.js as a Player. Creating chunks with ffmpeg seems to work fine, but when want to create the manifest it says  `Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp9, none, 640x480): unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options` and at the end `Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)`.

**Commands I use**

```
ffmpeg -re -r 25 -i Dash/strm.webm
 -map 0:v:0
 -pix_fmt yuv420p
 -c:v libvpx-vp9
 -s 640x480 -keyint_min 25 -g 25 
 -speed 6 -threads 8 -static-thresh 0 -max-intra-rate 300 
 -deadline realtime -lag-in-frames 0 -error-resilient 1
 -f webm_chunk 
 -header "Dash/glass_360.hdr"
 -chunk_start_index 1
 Dash\glass_360_%d.chk
```

*Manifest*

```
ffmpeg ^
 -f webm_dash_manifest -live 1
 -r 25
 -i Dash/glass_360.hdr
 -c copy
 -map 0
 -r 25
 -framerate 25
 -f webm_dash_manifest -live 1
 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0"
 -chunk_start_index 1
 -chunk_duration_ms 1000
 -time_shift_buffer_depth 7200
 -minimum_update_period 7200
 Dash/glass_live_manifest.mpd
```

*Manifest Output*

```
 libavutil      56. 49.100 / 56. 49.100
  libavcodec     58. 87.101 / 58. 87.101
  libavformat    58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 83.100 /  7. 83.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[webm_dash_manifest @ 0000015f19f2ea40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: vp9, none, 640x480): unspecified pixel format
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, webm_dash_manifest, from 'Dash/glass_360.hdr':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.43.100
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9, none, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ALPHA_MODE      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.87.101 libvpx-vp9
      webm_dash_manifest_file_name: glass_360.hdr
      webm_dash_manifest_track_number: 1
Output #0, webm_dash_manifest, to 'stream_manifest.mpd':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.43.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9, none, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=2-31, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ALPHA_MODE      : 1
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.87.101 libvpx-vp9
      webm_dash_manifest_file_name: glass_360.hdr
      webm_dash_manifest_track_number: 1
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=       1kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
```

**glass_live_manifest.mpd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MPD
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011"
  xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011"
  type="dynamic"
  minBufferTime="PT1S"
  profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
  availabilityStartTime="2021-04-01T12:49:59Z"
  timeShiftBufferDepth="PT7200S"
  minimumUpdatePeriod="PT7200S">
<Period id="0" start="PT0S" >
<AdaptationSet id="0" mimeType="video/webm" codecs="vp9" lang="eng" bitstreamSwitching="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1">
<ContentComponent id="1" type="video"/>
<SegmentTemplate timescale="1000" duration="1000" media="glass_$RepresentationID$_$Number$.chk" startNumber="1" initialization="glass_$RepresentationID$.hdr"/>
<Representation id="360" bandwidth="1000000" width="640" height="480" codecs="vp9" mimeType="video/webm" startsWithSAP="1"></Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
</Period>
</MPD>
```

#### UPDATE

I fixed the "warnings" by changing the comands like this:

```
ffmpeg -re -r 25 -i Dash/strm.webm
-map 0:v:0
-pix_fmt yuv420p
-c:v libvpx
-s 640x480 -keyint_min 60 -g 60 -speed 6 -tile-columns 4 -frame-parallel 1 -threads 8 -static-thresh 0 -max-intra-rate 300 -deadline realtime -lag-in-frames 0 -error-resilient 1
-b:v 3000k
-f webm_chunk
-header "Dash/glass_360.hdr"
-chunk_start_index 1 Dash/glass_360_%d.chk
-map 0:a:0
-c:a libvorbis
-b:a 128k -ar 44100
-f webm_chunk
-audio_chunk_duration 2000
-header Dash/glass_171.hdr
-chunk_start_index 1 Dash/glass_171_%d.chk

ffmpeg
-f webm_dash_manifest -live 1
-i Dash/glass_360.hdr
-f webm_dash_manifest -live 1
-i Dash/glass_171.hdr
-c copy
-map 0 -map 1
-f webm_dash_manifest -live 1
-adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=0 id=1,streams=1"
-chunk_start_index 1
-chunk_duration_ms 2000
-time_shift_buffer_depth 7200
-minimum_update_period 7200 Dash/glass_video_manifest.mpd
```

However, it's still not working.

Comment: Consider increasing the value for the `-analyzeduration` and `-probesize` options.

Comment: @llogan Nothing has changed.